# Can't get the sentence

Tags: meaning

Is that sentence poorly written? I mean the word *elsewhere* means  *in or to another place*, and *before* is a preposition of time, not the place.

> [But, water plays an even bigger role elsewhere, before it's ever frozen into those perfectly aesthetic, slow-melting ice spheres, or bottled up for exorbitantly priced sales all on its own.](http://www.eater.com/drinks/2015/11/25/9784954/spirits-water-purity-water-sources)

Answer (score 3):

The role that water plays elsewhere is a role which it carries out earlier in it's lifecycle.

i.e. it has other roles, and these are not played out here in the topic at hand.

The other roles happen in an earlier part of the sequence of: evaporation; cloud; precipitation as rain or snow, etc.; run-off; capture; bottling.

Answer (score 0):

"before" is a preposition and a conjunction. As a preposition it refers mostly to time, but it can refer to place also in special cases.

In your example "before" is a conjunction, introducing a subordinate clause. See Oald, before, conjunction
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/before_2